# How to select uniq child from parent in ActiveRecord in a single query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a modal named `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many: :posts
end
```

and another modal named `Post`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

if i have a scoped posts object (say `posts = Post.where(id: [1,2,3,4]`)

how can i query the uniq users of all posts using active record methods

i know it can be done in two queries, is there a way to do it in a single query ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`User.where id: posts.distinct.select(:user_id)`

Comment: Will it run two queries? Once for `posts.distinct.select(:user_id)` and once for `User.where id: [--results--]`

Answer (score 2):

Try, as indicated in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables):

```
User.joins(:posts).where(posts: {id: [1,2,3,4]})
```

Or, if you already have an instance called `posts`:

```
User.joins(:posts).where(posts: {id: posts})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one single query, by thinking about the way the inner join works. If you use `User.joins(:posts)`, this performs an inner join and will return only the users with at least 1 post. Furthermore, you want to filter on those posts, and you can do that using the `merge` method in ActiveRecord. The result would be:

```
User.joins(:posts).merge(Post.where(id: [1,2,3,4]))
```

This creates a single SQL query

Comment: Why would you use `merge` when you can directly access to `posts` after using `joins`?

Answer (score 0):

1 query with some ruby processing

```
Post.eager_load(:user).where(id: [1,2,3,4]).map(&:user)
```

Comment: While the OP didn't specify it in the question, this will prevent any further querying on the resulting `User` enumerable as it is an `array` instead of some flavor of  ActiveRecord enumerable.